# rxjs timeout: distinguish time expired from source error

Tags: rxjs, observable

Using RxJS 6.5, I subscribe to a stream and I'd like to take two distinct actions:
 - one when the source errors
 - another when the source takes too long to send data (timeout)

Here is what I currently have

```js
source$.pipe(
  timeoutWith(5000, log('timeout!')),
  catchError(log('error!'))
).subscribe();

function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return of(null);
}
```

When my source takes longer than 5000ms to emit, I get the expected result: timeout!

However when my source throws an error early (before the 5000ms), both lines execute.  It seems as though it `timeoutWith` is triggered whenever the source did not emit, even if it errored.

How can I set up a pipe so that the timeout logic only runs if time has actually elapsed, not because the stream was aborted due to an error?

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/embed/rxjs-playground-pz934?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your correct operator to use is `timeout` instead of `timeoutWith` and I'll explain.

`timeoutWith` will - [Subscribe to second Observable if no emission occurs in given time span.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeoutwith.html) and this is not your needs.

`timeout` will - [Error if no value is emitted before specified duration](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html) which is best for your needs/

Using `timeout` in your pipe should look like this:

```
source$.pipe(
  catchError(() => log('func error!')), // will log only when your source throws an error
  timeout(5000),
  catchError(() => log('timeout error!')) // will log only if your source as timed-out for 5000
).subscribe();
```

> [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-timeout-operator)